# how to unlink environments in Anaconda?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I'm Bobby and I work on a linux server. My conda environments list is a mix of environments from both me and Sammy's linux accounts. The base environment points to Sammy. How do I "unlink" Sammy's environments?

Note: I **cannot** delete Sammy's environments as he needs them.

```sh
base                  *  /nas/maps_work/sammy/miniconda3
white                    /nas/maps_work/sammy/miniconda3/envs/white
scoop                    /nas/maps_work/sammy/miniconda3/envs/scoop
scoop-ui                 /nas/maps_work/sammy/miniconda3/envs/scoop-ui
setupmode                /nas/maps_work/sammy/miniconda3/envs/setupmode
property                 /nas/maps_work/sammy/miniconda3/envs/property
white                    /nas/maps_work/bobby/miniconda3/envs/white
scoop                    /nas/maps_work/bobby/miniconda3/envs/scoop
scoop-ui                 /nas/maps_work/bobby/miniconda3/envs/scoop-ui
setupmode                /nas/maps_work/bobby/miniconda3/envs/setupmode
property                 /nas/maps_work/bobby/miniconda3/envs/property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a conda configuration file in your home directory: `touch ~/.condarc` and add the following configuration. The envs_dir lets you specify where the envs are located, for advanced conda configuration you can refer to the documentation [conda configuration](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html#specify-environment-directories-envs-dirs):

```
envs_dirs:
  - /nas/maps_work/bobby/miniconda3/envs
```

Comment: I already have this. It's still showing the other environments.

Comment: what's the output of  ```conda info --base``` ?

Comment: If it points to the 'sammy' user conda installation you can set your miniconda installation in your terminal (.bash_profile or .zshrc) configuration. ```export PATH=~/<YOUR_CONDA_INSTALLATION>/bin:$PATH```

Comment: conda info --base returns: /nas/maps_work/sammy/miniconda3